# Add a reminder to search near the list of "Questions that may already have your answer"

Tags: feature-request, search, asking-questions

We can often see that basically the same question is asked again and again. (Especially on bigger sites and most often by new inexperienced users.) This naturally leads to closing as duplicates, sometimes some downvotes - and for new users this can eventually lead to question ban.

Perhaps it might be useful to remind more often the users the "search before asking" rule. (I am aware of the fact that this is shown already in the help center. And that several sites display to a user before *asking the first question* the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) page which contains this advice. Still, judging by the number of duplicates, it seems that it goes often unnoticed.)

When asking a new question, a list of "Questions that may already have your answer" is displayed. Perhaps already this might remind the asker that they might search on the site for similar questions. But maybe an additional reminder can help.

**Suggestion:**  Add somewhere near the text "Questions that may already have your answer" a reminder to search before asking. (Something like: "Do not forget to search on the site before asking a new question." or "It is recommended that before asking you search whether the question already is answered on the site.") This could be displayed in a smaller font and perhaps below this text and above the list of questions. And it could contains some reasonable link related to searching (for example, search-related part of the help-center or a link directly to search).

Some additional remarks:

- Another possible place where every user could see this reminder be displayed would be the "How to Ask" box displayed on the right when a new question is posted. However, this place might be too full after further additions, especially on the sites where it has already been customized with some additional information. This is the reason why I suggested a different place.
- The link included in the text should probably customizable pre sites. Some sites have on meta their own community maintained FAQ about searching and they might prefer this link to the generic link suitable on most sites.

Comment: I think this kind of advice should be addressed to those users aimed simply to find an answer. Therefore a first step should be filter out those users from the others aimed to receive a simple hint, to discuss specific isses and more in general interested to some interaction with other users. We could for example require the new users to declare explicetely the that main aim of their question.